# Participating in Match prediction giveaways without spending money

Tags: halal-haram

I recently participated in a free entry giveaway and the people who correctly predicted the scoreline of the football match were given 25 dollars , apparently i won it and i want to ask is this permissible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, We would like to emphasize the fact that only Almighty Allah have the knowledge of unseen.
If prediction is based on calculation or analysis based on experience and current event, then it is not haram. But if it is religiously oriented prediction, like saying; you're going to have baby by middle of next year, this is clearly haram.

Comment: I predicted the result by seeing the previous match results and performances of both teams and was not religiously oriented or anything , is the money halal?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Your prediction is based on calculations